# jQuery Color Animation Using Recursion causes Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, recursion, jquery-animate

I built a simple jQuery animation that uses recursion to repeat a function that runs the animation over and over again endlessly. It works and looks cool, but in the console it is throwing the error: "**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**"... Is there another way to accomplish an endless animation loop without using recursion or another approach CSS3, or jQuery based solution perhaps that will not make the browser throw errors?

Here is the working code at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flatiron_school/0busdnv7/5/

Here is the code included below in case you hate jsfiddle:

```
<a>1</a> <a>2</a> <a>3</a> <a>4</a> <a>5</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $a1 = $('a').eq(0),
      $a2 = $('a').eq(1),
      $a3 = $('a').eq(2),
      $a4 = $('a').eq(3),
      $a5 = $('a').eq(4),
      links = [$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5];
      delays = [100,200,300,400,500];

  function colorChange() {
    for (i=0; i < links.length; i++) {    
      var $el = links[i],
          amount = delays[i];
      $el.delay(amount).animate({'background-color': 'rgb(255,80,72)'},400);
      $el.delay(amount).animate({'background-color': 'rgb(64,80,44)'},400);
      $el.delay(amount).animate({'background-color': 'rgb(176,24,98)'},400);
      $el.delay(amount).animate({'background-color': 'rgb(42,157,200)'},400);
    }
    colorChange();
  }
  colorChange();
</script>
```

Any help appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: since you are calling `colorChange` inside `colorChange`.. it creates a infinite depth stack.. which is causing the error

Comment: I really didn't understand what you are trying to do... but to fix the error you can us a timeout in `colorChange` like `setTimeout(colorChange, 1);` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yw7g6xac/1/

Comment: can you define the animation you are looking for?

Comment: Ahh this works Arun P. Thank you! Using setTimeout(colorChange, 1) allows enough time apparently that the stack error doesn't appear. I have my updated code here using Aruns strategy: http://jsfiddle.net/flatiron_school/0busdnv7/6/

Comment: but I still feel it can be written in a better way... we can have a look if you can define the animation you are looking for... your current strategy will eatup a lot of system resources since it constantly keep executing the method `colorChange`

Comment: I see what you mean... Basically I was trying to get the circle links to fade colors at different times so they are out of sync and appear to change color asynchronously.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yw7g6xac/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments... the problem with your code is the infinite recursion in your method `colorChange` which will break the stack limit of the browser...

The dump solution I suggested is to use a timeout in the recursive call which will break the recursion and call the method using a fresh stack.. like

```
setTimeOut(colorChange, 1);
```

But as a real solution try

```
var colors = ['rgb(255,80,72)', 'rgb(64,80,44)', 'rgb(176,24,98)', 'rgb(42,157,200)'];

$('a').each(function () {
    changeColor($(this));
});

function changeColor($el) {
    $el.animate({
        'background-color': colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    }, 400, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            changeColor($el);
        }, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 400));
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yw7g6xac/)

Comment: I updated this to use module pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/flatiron_school/yw7g6xac/6/

Comment: If anyone needs to randomly fade colors on HTML elements this discussion led to me creating a jQuery plugin (using Arun's approach) here: https://plugins.jquery.com/colorcycle/